# Using the cat file.fa | grep -c "TATA" > results.txt in a python script

Tags: python, unix

I have around 400 datasets that I named dataID_F.fas and dataID_R.fas. For each dataID there is a dataID_F.fas and dataID_R.fas. For each dataID I want to compare occurrence of a specific region for example "-AG-GT-" and when present in a particular sequence it occurs only once as I have trimmed the specific region I am searching. I was using two commands first to count the number of sequences and the next one to count the unique sites Im looking for:
cat DataID_F(or R).fas | grep -c ">" (total sequences)
cat DataID_F(or R).fas | grep -c "-AG-GT-" (total variants).

So this process is very tedious considering the number of datasets that I have, and I was thinking of generating a python script that can read open all the fasta files in the directory (files with standard naming DataID_F.fas/DataID_R.fas), count the total number of sequences, total variants and then calculates the percentages ((total variants/total senqueces)*100) for each file and tabulate the results in a csv or text format. Here is what I thought of doing but I got lost along the way and didn't know how to put the whole thing together.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import os
import csv

#write output in a table with three columns namely filename, Total sequences, Total variants, Percentage of variants 

csvfile = "./" #path to output csv
def print_table(table):
    from tabulate import tabulate
        tabulate(table, headers=["Filename","Total sequences", "Total variants", "Percentage variants/total sequences"])
    print_table(table)


with open('query.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip() # remove trailing whitespace such as '\n'
        subprocess.call(['/bin/grep', line, 'my2.txt'])

cat DataID_F(or R).fas | grep -c ">" > Results.csv (total sequences)
cat DataID_F(or R).fas | grep -c "-AAT-T-" > Results.csv (total variants)

from __future__ import division #calculating the percentage variants
```

Comment: So you would like to "translate" the two lines starting with `cat` in python language? (or is there anything else to check in your script?).

Comment: Yes I want to translate the cat to python language as well as managing to get the results in the table format.